# Convert Date format in a text string in php

Tags: php, string, date

```
$string = this is my message in 12-10-12, Orlando
```

i want to convert it to `$new = this is my message in 12th October 2012, Orlando`.

Please help me with php code

Comment: I want to code that can identify the date format in the string and replace it by desired date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
function convert_date($hit)
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("y-m-d", $hit[0]);

    if (!$date) //invalid date supplied, return original string
        return $hit[0]; 

    return $date->format("jS F Y");
}

$string = "this is my message in 12-10-12, Orlando or maybe 13-11-21";
$string = preg_replace_callback("~(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})~", "convert_date", $string);
echo $string; //this is my message in 12th October 2012, Orlando or maybe 21st November 2013
```

Look at the [php date modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), the [DateTime extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for further information.

Comment: It worked.Thanks @ David Muller